# How to start a subprocess, that is exited when my main process exits

Tags: go

I have a simple Go application, which occasionally runs bash scripts in the background.

For simplicity, I am just starting chrome with a webpage in the background.

```
#!/bin/env bash

chrome https://www.google.com
```

Now 2 things can happen:

1. There is already a chrome window open. In this case, chrome opens the URL in the existing window and exits.
2. There is not already a chrome window open. In this case, the chrome command becomes the chrome main process and is bound to the browser window. This means the process does not exit if I do not close the browser window *and* the browser exits if my Go application exits (because it's a child process).

I do not want the second case to happen! Because in that case, if I quit the application chrome also quits and I do not want that.

Can I somehow in Go start a process (with something like `exec.Command`) and completely disconnect it from my application, so that the process runs independently (does not exit with my process, does not block it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
package main
import "os/exec"

func main() {
   exec.Command(`C:\Windows\notepad`).Start()
}
```

To respond to a comment. Regarding `Wait`, if you call `Wait`, it's essentially the same thing as calling `Run`. The point of `Wait` is it allows for you to put code between the start of the command, and when you are waiting for it to complete.

Contrast that with `Run`, where the "Start" and "Wait" happen one right after the other, without the option to put anything in between. Or in this case, where you don't want the `Wait` at all.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec#Cmd.Start

Comment: It works  ... I don't completly understand why. If I store the command and at the and call `Wait` on it, it does not work. But if I don't it works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on operating system, i will assume you use windows for this task.

By using the --user-data-dir parameter you can have it start a new one. It should do what you ask

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    path := "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    cmd := exec.Command(path, "--user-data-dir="+os.Getenv("localappdata")+"\\Google\\Chrome\\InstalledApps\\organisation-name\\project-name")
    cmd.Start()
}
```

The chrome will run independent

Note that --user-data-dir creates a folder with chrome files that is changing size constantly between 16mb to 100mb per application.

And if you want to do the opposite, where the main process is attached to the chrome process (bidirectional open/close), then you can use a signal and cmd.Wait as below.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    path := "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    cmd := exec.Command(path, "--user-data-dir="+os.Getenv("localappdata")+"\\Google\\Chrome\\InstalledApps\\organisation-name\\project-name")
    cmd.Start()

    signalHandler := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalHandler, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGQUIT)

    // running till terminal (termination)
    go func() {
        <-signalHandler // waiting for termination
        cmd.Process.Kill()
    }()

    // running till exit chrome window
    cmd.Wait()
}
```